# sum between two strings

Tags: bash, awk, sed

How I can sum between two strings? I have a file with hundreds of thousands lines and I need to sum column 2 and the sum need to be placed above the string. For example:

cat inputfile

```
comp 2 3 ter 0
2 3
1 5
2 2
2 1
comp 1 2 ter 2
1 2
0 2
6 4
```

I need the sum of the second column after comp to be placed in third column of comp.

cat output

```
comp 2 11 ter 0
2 3
1 5
2 2
2 1
comp 1 8 ter 2
1 2
0 2
6 4
```

I tried this but it is only add the second column all together

```
awk '{sum+=$2;}END{print $0}'
```

Comment: On SO we do encourage users to add their own efforts which they have put in order to solve their own problem, so kindly do add the same and let us know then.

Comment: Thanks for adding your efforts in your post, try to always add them(in code form) very first time of asking question itself, so that you could avoid down votes then(though I don't down vote), cheers and happy learning on this greats site SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following, using `tac` + `awk` here.

```
tac Input_file | 
awk '
/comp/{
    $3=sum
    print
    sum=""
    next
}
{
    sum+=$NF
}
1;
END{
    if(sum){
      $3=sum
      print
    }
}
' | tac
```

***Explanation of above approach:***

- Since `comp` string line is coming before and its sum part lines are coming after it, that's the main reason for using `tac` here, which will reverse the Input_file lines and then `comp` line will come after other lines by which we can easily sequentially read by `awk` code.
- Since output after processing of `tac` then `awk` will be in reverse order so again we have put 1 `tac`  in order to take output into original Input_file format.

Output will be as follows.

```
comp 2 10 ter 0
2 3
1 5
2 2
comp 1 8 ter 2
1 2
0 2
6 4
```